# java.lang.InstantiationError: com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.collection.QueryPlan while running spark-cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to get data using dataframes from cassandra by using `spark-cassandra-connector` but getting below exception.

Note: Connection is successful to cassandra.
Spark version: 2.4.1
spark-cassandra-connector version: 2.5.1

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-10-01 11:32:01.649 ERROR 17404 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.InstantiationError: com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.collection.QueryPlan
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:122) ~[spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.newQueryPlan(LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.java:155) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:193) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.(CqlRequestHandler.java:171) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:54) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:78) ~[java-driver-core-shaded-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:43) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$$anonfun$1.apply(TokenFactory.scala:99) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$$anonfun$1.apply(TokenFactory.scala:98) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:129) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$.forSystemLocalPartitioner(TokenFactory.scala:98) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.SplitSizeEstimator$class.tokenFactory(SplitSizeEstimator.scala:9) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tokenFactory$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:64) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tokenFactory(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:64) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.SplitSizeEstimator$class.estimateDataSize(SplitSizeEstimator.scala:12) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.SplitSizeEstimator$class.estimateSplitCount(SplitSizeEstimator.scala:21) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.estimateSplitCount(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:64) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$1.apply$mcI$sp(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:228) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:228) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:228) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) ~[scala-library-2.11.12.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.partitionGenerator$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:228) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.partitionGenerator(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:224) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:273) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) ~[scala-library-2.11.12.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1168) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you posted indicates that the embedded Java driver is not able to generate a query plan -- list of Cassandra nodes to connect to as coordinators. There is possibly an issue with how you've defined the contact points.

You normally need to specify a contact point with the `cassandra.connection.host` parameter. Here's an example of how you would start a Spark shell using the connector:

```
$ spark-shell
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra_ip
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions
```

In your case, it looks like you're creating a connection from Spring Boot and you are probably running into conflicts with dependencies.

You will need to update your original question with details of your configuration including details of the dependencies plus what command you're running to connect to Spark so those answering your question have a better idea of what the problem is. Cheers!